# Problem with Javascript Date function in IE 7, returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date, twitter

I have a twitter feed and I create a new date obj so I can format the date to my liking.

`var created = new Date(this.created_at)` works in firefox and chrome but not in IE7. I seem to be having trouble passing the date through the `new Date()` function. It just returns undefined and NaN.

Here is the code. If you try to test it out don't forget to include jquery. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Twitter Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >

$(function(){
$.getJSON("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/google.json?count=1&callback=?", function(data){
    $.each(data, function(){
        var created = new Date(this.created_at)
        $("<div></div>").append("<ul><li>Unformatted: " + this.created_at + "</li><li>Formatted: " + created + "</li></ul>").appendTo("body")
    });

})  

})

</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll want to make sure the date is parsed as UTC, because otherwise javascript will interpret it as a date in your local timezone.

The date looks like this: `Tue Jul 13 23:18:36 +0000 2010`

You can parse it like this:

```
function parseDate(str) {
  var v=str.split(' ');
  return new Date(Date.parse(v[1]+" "+v[2]+", "+v[5]+" "+v[3]+" UTC"));
}
```

Which will give the correct date/time in the local timezone, for example: `Tue Jul 13 2010 19:18:36 GMT-0400 (EDT)`

So that should leave your code looking something like this:

```
$(function(){
  $.getJSON("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/google.json?count=1&callback=?", function(data){
    $.each(data, function(){
      var created = parseDate(this.created_at);
      $("<div></div>").append("<ul><li>Unformatted: " + this.created_at + "</li><li>Formatted: " + created + "</li></ul>").appendTo("body");
    });
  });
  function parseDate(str) {
    var v=str.split(' ');
    return new Date(Date.parse(v[1]+" "+v[2]+", "+v[5]+" "+v[3]+" UTC"));
  } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This works great. I'm still learning. So if I understand right. You created a new function called parseDate and passed that the date string and created a new array by splitting it wherever there was a space. Then you reorganized it in the appropriate format.

Also, I'm new to this site. So what do I have to do to give you rep points?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it. Also adding 'UTC' or 'GMT' at the end is important; without that js will assume it's a time in the user's local timezone (it's not, of course; twitter's server doesn't necessarily know what timezone the user is in). You can click the triangle above the `0` beside my answer to +1 me, but i think you need to have created an account to do it. :)

Comment: What do you call this format?  (Tue Jul 13 23:18:36 +0000 2010)

Comment: @brad - nothing as far as I know... the year is after the timezone; I don't think there are any standardized formats like that. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong, though.

Comment: @no I didn't think so, but I wanted to at least attempt to find out.  It's a bit weird that twitter uses such a non-standard format.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for your parser. I was too lazy to fix this myself, this one works very solid!

Answer (score 3):

I've found the [jQuery Globalization Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate) date parsing to work best.  Other methods had cross-browser issues and stuff like date.js had not been updated in quite a while.

You also don't need a datePicker on the page.  You can just call something similar to the example given in the docs:

```
$.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', '2007-01-26');
```

Comment: This does great for dates, but doesn't parse times.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I made to correct this!

```
$tweetList.append('<p><span class="twitterdate">' + parseTwitterDate(item.created_at) + location + '</span></p>');

var month=new Array();
month[0]="January";
month[1]="February";
month[2]="March";
month[3]="April";
month[4]="May";
month[5]="June";
month[6]="July";
month[7]="August";
month[8]="September";
month[9]="October";
month[10]="November";
month[11]="December";

function parseTwitterDate($stamp) {
    var v=$stamp.split(' ');
    var date = new Date(Date.parse(v[1]+" "+v[2]+", "+v[5]+" "+v[3]+" UTC"));
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var ampm = hour<12 ? ' AM' : ' PM';
    return date.getHours() +':'+ date.getMinutes() +' '+ ampm +' '+ date.getDate() +' '+ month[date.getMonth()] +' '+ date.getFullYear();
}
```

And this give me "19:38 PM 23 April 2012" on Chrome, IE and Firefox.