# Timeago jquery plugin does not display on IE. How can I fix it?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, timeago

I use Tweetable plugin and Timeago plugin to display tweets on my website. You can see at : http://www.beautyworkssalon.com/products.html  (the "Follow Us On" section on left comlumn). I want to "n days ago" below the tweet. However it only display on Firefox, Chrome. It doesn't display on IE.

I see at : https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago/issues/35  . They said that it's an IE's issue, not Timeago plugin.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Try looking a little harder: possible duplicate of [Problem with Javascript Date function in IE 7, returns NaN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243546/problem-with-javascript-date-function-in-ie-7-returns-nan)

Comment: This link give a manual solution to do it. I want to fix this issue using Timeago plugin. May you help me ?

Comment: You need to fix the plugin with the script in the link