# Javascript Date.parse on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have this script I'm using for working with dates:

```
time = "Mon May 20 13:19:13 +0000 2013"; /// sample value
var date = new Date(Date.parse(time));
var diff = (((new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000);
var day_diff = Math.floor(diff / 86400);
```

It works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but it's not ok on Internet Explorer (I've checked with IE10). Any ideeas how can I make it work?

(The time string I'm getting it's from a twitter feed).

Later edit: example http://jsfiddle.net/BUv5v/3/

Comment: What does "not OK" mean?

Comment: Make what work? What is the problem? What is not working?

Comment: There is a documented problem with dates in IE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020508/ie-javascript-date-parsing-error

Comment: Open this link in Chrome and IE : http://jsfiddle.net/BUv5v/3/

Comment: Why do you even want to use `Date.parse()`? It is working by just passing the string to the constructor.

Comment: Amberlamps, did you even opened that link in Internet explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.parse()` [will not parse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3020641/1850609) a date in this format `Tue Dec 05 2006 16:47:20 GMT-0500` in IE.

A workaround is to use [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3243599/1850609) to parse that format in both browsers:

```
function parseDate(str) {
    var v = str.split(' ');
    return new Date(Date.parse(v[1] + " " + v[2] + ", " + v[5] + " " + v[3] + " UTC"));
}
```

Thus, the ending code would be:

```
time = "Mon May 20 13:19:13 +0000 2013"; /// sample value
var date = parseDate(time);                     // <---------------- changed here
var diff = (((new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000);
var day_diff = Math.floor(diff / 86400);
```

Testing fiddle <sup>(tested in Chrome 27, Firefox 13 and IE 9)</sup>: http://jsfiddle.net/R3Ez9/