# Javascript Invalid Date Error in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, date

Relatively simple javascript here, not sure why IE hates me (treat others how you want to be treated I suppose).

```
var newDate = new Date("2012, 11, 2 19:30:00:000");
alert(newDate);
```

This works in Chrome and FF, but IE outputs "Invalid Date"

**Fiddle me this**: http://jsfiddle.net/k6yD6/

Comment: I actually get invalid date in Firefox as well (latest version, 16.0.1).

Comment: Just make sure you're using a properly supported format. This question has been asked plenty of times before, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020508/ie-javascript-date-parsing-error

Comment: for IE its dateObj = new Date(year, month, date[, hours[, minutes[, seconds[,ms]]]])

Comment: Don't worry. IE hates everyone

Comment: Or Microsoft could just BE NICE like other browsers! .. Terrible browser

Comment: https://www.csgpro.com/blog/2016/08/a-bad-date-with-internet-explorer-11-trouble-with-new-unicode-characters-in-javascript-date-strings . This post will be helpful for someone :)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The string given to the date constructor [should be an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 formatted date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). In your example it isn't. Try the following:

```
new Date("2012-11-02T19:30:00.000Z");
```

or using an [alternate constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
new Date(2012, 11, 2, 19, 30, 0)
```

Comment: thanks, the alternate constructor works however the first one you listed doesn't seem to in any browser

Comment: @DougieBear Answer updated - I had missed a required zero before the day

Comment: new Date("2012-11-02T19:30:00.000Z"); The milliseconds can be ommitted, but if included must be preceded by a dot, not a colon.

Comment: I had to split my date string and add a T & Z !!

Answer (score 9):

IE does not seem to support millisecond and months in Numerical String. Try this:

```
new Date("November 2, 2012 19:30:00");
```

or

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

Comment: `new Date("November 2, 2012 19:30:00");` - This saved me a lot of pain.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue with Internet Explorer. This is how I was formatting the date and time initially,

```
function formatDateTime(date, formatString = 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A') {
  return moment(new Date(date)).format(formatString);
}
```

The problem was with `new Date()`. I just removed it as it was already a `UTC` date. So it is just,

```
return moment(date).format(formatString);
```

This worked for me in all browsers including **IE**.

Comment: OP does not mention using moment.js library.

Comment: Other people besides OP view this page looking for answers, and some of them are using moment.js

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
var newDate = moment("2012, 11, 2 19:30:00:000").toDate();
alert(newDate);
```

This will work in IE too.

Answer (score 1):

To work in `IE`, date should be in proper format. I fixed this same issue by using below format:

```js
var tDate = new Date('2011'+"-"+'01'+"-"+'01'); //Year-Month-day
```

Comment: When I passed this year-month-day format into my code, it fixed the problem... gotta give you a 1 up. However, I didn't need the new Date, just change the format as a string and the date appeared correctly on the server side via IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

```
var time = new Date("2021-12-01 17:02:12");
if(isNaN(time))
{
    time= new Date(date.replace(/ /g,'T')+'.000Z');
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it