# get date difference in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to get the difference of of these dates.
e.g

```
var current_date = new Date();
var date_from_database = "2013/06/10 15:00:00";
var difference = data_from_datebase - current_date;

   // so the result should be: 7
```

I want to get how many days left buy subtracting the current day on specific day like the example above. How can I do this on javascript?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The following might work:

```
var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var firstDate = new Date(2008,01,12);
var secondDate = new Date(2008,01,22);

var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date_from_database = new Date("2013/06/10 15:00:00");
var date1= new Date();
var date_diff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date_from_database .getTime()/86400000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to compare it with the current day:

```
var firstDate = new Date(2008,01,12);
var secondDate = new Date();

var timeDiff = Math.abs(firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 

alert(diffDays);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/imac/TEjqX/

You will have to modify the date you receive from the database to addapt it to the needed parameter for `date()`. 
You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13091576/1081396) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript could be very pesky in processing the datetime variables.

Do not reinvent the wheel. I often use the [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) library.

In particular, the time.js file features the [`TimeSpan()` function](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/source/browse/trunk/src/time.js) that processes datetime differences.

References:

- [date.js main page](http://www.datejs.com/)
- [date.js @ google code](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/)
- [time.js page](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/source/browse/trunk/src/time.js)