# IE browser Date Time Issue

Tags: javascript, java, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

On IE 11 browser the below statement is returning an invalid date response: new Date("2016-03-09T22:40:05.653-0800").
Where as on the chrome/firefox it is returning the valid date.

Please suggest me !!

Answer (score 2):

This is *nearly* an ISO-8601 formatted date/time, but not quite... the UTC offset doesn't have a colon in it. It looks like Chrome and Firefox aren't being quite as picky with their ISO-8601 parsing as IE.

If you change the code to:

```
new Date("2016-03-09T22:40:05.653-08:00")
```

... then it's fine in both Chrome and IE11. (I haven't tested Firefox, but I'd expect it to be fine.)

"-0800" is a valid UTC offset in *basic* format of ISO-8601, but that doesn't have colons. Neither Chrome nor IE want to handle a properly-formatted basic ISO-8601 value, e.g. "20160309T224005-0800".

Answer (score 1):

The string given to the date constructor should be an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 formatted date. In your example it isn't. Try the following:

```
new Date("2012-11-02T19:30:00.000Z");
```

Comment: what does that mean n how it is working in the other browsers ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091523/javascript-invalid-date-error-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 0):

According to [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) I believe that the timezone should be specified as `-08:00`.