# Javascript Date Object from date string

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer

I have a string with the following format `"2018-04-24 11:56:27+0000"`. This is a UTC time and it should be converted to local time.

I want to create a Date Object that represents the same date in Chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE (all latest). This format works for all browsers except IE. I use it like

```
new Date("2018-04-24 11:56:27+0000")
```

I can not change the format because it comes from another service (I only could reformat it in my frontend logic). Is there a way to create a Date Object from this also in IE, or is there any conversion algorithm to convert this format to some IE compatible format in Javascript and only for IE?

[Javascript Invalid Date Error in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091523) does not solve my problem because they use local time, not UTC in constructos. I can't do the same with UTC times

Comment: Which IE version are we talking about?

Comment: If you know *for sure* that you only get UTC times then `let [date, t] = str.split(' '); let [time] = t.split(/[+\-]/); new Date(\`${date}T${time}Z\`);` should work. After being run through babel of course.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091523/javascript-invalid-date-error-in-internet-explorer

Comment: @AntonioPangallo if a question is a duplicate you can flag it as such, even (I think) at your rep level.

Comment: @getjackx all browsers latest version

Comment: @AntonioPangallo I already found this question, but they use local time to create the Date object not UTC time. I can not find a way to this with UTC time string in constructor that works in all listed browsers

Comment: @bpoiss—the issue is that the string does not conform to the [format specified in ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date-time-string-format), so parsing using the built-in parser is implementation dependent. Either parse it yourself (2 lines of code) or use a library.

Comment: @JaredSmith—vs the much shorter and more compatible `var b = str.split(/\D/);new Date(Date.UTC(b[0],--b[1],b[2],b[3],b[4],b[5]));`. ;-)