# Date return NAN in IE

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE JavaScript date parsing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020508/ie-javascript-date-parsing-error)

This code working fine in chrome and firefox but it didn't work in IE and safari. It return NAN in IE and invalid date in safair.

```
var date = new Date("2012-10-17T08:15:19.500-05:00");
var now = new Date();
var difference = now - date;

document.write( "Date: " + date.toLocaleString() + "<br/>");
document.write( "Now: " + now.toLocaleString() + "<br/>");
document.write( "Difference: " + differenceToString(difference) );

function differenceToString(milliseconds) {
    var seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
    var numyears = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);
    var numdays = Math.floor((seconds % 31536000) / 86400);
    var numhours = Math.floor(((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) / 3600);
    var numminutes = Math.floor((((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
    var numseconds = Math.floor((((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) % 60);
    return numyears + " years, " + numdays + " days, " + numhours + " hours, " + numminutes + " minutes, " + numseconds + " seconds";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RYS3R/

Any idea would be great help.

Thanks

Comment: What part of the code does not work? Is it right the first line?

Comment: I'm marking as a dupe, but be sure to check out [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) - It's a great library for parsing and working with dates in Javascript!

Comment: @bergi : Yes First Line.

Comment: Then please ask only about that, like "Why do IE and Safari not accept my date format while Chrome and FF do?"

Comment: The date string formats supported by the Date constructor have only one guarantee: that the it understands the same string format as what it outputs by default.  Definitely use a library for dates, since this is a weak area in Javascript functionality.

Comment: @Mike:It was not duplicate.I do have a different formate of string than the link you provided.

Comment: @ravipatel - The point is, different browsers support different formats.  Pick a format that they all have in common and you're good.

Comment: @mike: I do understand. But i got the plain text from xml and i can't edit the xml the way i want. It generated from database.So i got "2012-10-17T08:15:19.500-05:00" as a plain text. Thanks

Comment: @ravipatel - Actually it appears not even date.js supports this format.  I think you'll have to parse it with RegEx first and extract each part.  Bummer.

Comment: @ravipatel - Just stumbled across [this library](http://momentjs.com/) too - Might be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `Z` before the timezone offset, to get valid JS-parsed date according to the [language specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15) - `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ±hh:mm` is the [only format it must accept](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.4.2). Try

```
var date = new Date("2012-10-17T08:15:19.500Z-05:00");
…
```

Comment: :: It is not working and as i said i can't edit the string it came from xml so i do not get "Z" in the string. So technically we could not do anything your solution.

Comment: IE does not respect the standard again? Poor thing. And you *can* change the string before passing it into the date constructor, nobody expected you to edit the source. You could do `.replace(/Z?([+-]?\d\d:\d\d)$/, "Z$1")` for example

Comment: :: I wil do that too. But your solution still doesn't supported in IE.

Comment: Oh, screw it! [IE supports ISO Date format since version 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx) - I couldn't find what could be parsed before