# Formatting date to new date not working in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, format, momentjs, utc

I currently have the following code:

```
lastLoginDate = "\/Date(1499994230140+0800)\/";
lastLoginDate = moment(lastLoginDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss UTC");
lastLoginDate = new Date(lastLoginDate);
```

This works in chrome. However when ran in IE, new Date returns invalid date. how do i achieve the same output in IE?

Comment: You need the format `Tue Dec 05 16:47:20 CDT 2006` -- [_IE JavaScript date parsing error_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020508/ie-javascript-date-parsing-error)

Comment: What on earth is `"\/Date(1499994230140+0800)\/"`? How did you end up with that?

Comment: Its being returned by the API

Comment: What API? If you have access, you should change that and not try to somehow parse it. This format makes absolutely no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolved my issue by changing format to yyyy/mm/dd instead of yyyy-mm-dd

```
moment(lastLoginDate).format("YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss UTC");
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me

Answer (score 0):

There is no need at all to format and then parse the date again. Just use [`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/):

```
lastLoginDate = moment(lastLoginDate).toDate();
```

If this does not work, then your `lastLoginDate` has a wrong format. You can read more about valid formats [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string into the Unix time and the timezone offset by using a regex.

This code below is easy to follow.

```js
const dateRegex = /^\/Date\((\d+)([-+]\d{4})\)\/$/;
const dateFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss Z';
  
let lastLoginDate = "\/Date(1499994230140+0800)\/";
console.log(parseTimestamp(lastLoginDate));

function parseTimestamp(timestamp) { 
  var groups = dateRegex.exec(timestamp);
  var unixTime = Math.floor(parseInt(groups[1], 10) / 1000);
  var timezoneOffset = groups[2];

  return moment.unix(unixTime).utcOffset(timezoneOffset).format(dateFormat);
}

// Output: 2017-07-14 09:03:50 +08:00
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can change the `let` and `const` statement declarations to `var` if it does not work in IE.